# How I can take more detailed LOG ? try catch

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, logging, try-catch

When I use try catch structure My code give me err to less detail
Like that

```
[UnhandledPromiseRejection: This error originated eith{
  code: 'ERR_UNHANDLED_REJECTION'
}
```

But in reality its give me like that

```
parsedHtmlPage.querySelectorAll('*').forEach((el{
                                           ^
TypeError: indexObject.img is not iterable
    at D:\githubprojects\projectMovieSite\dizitest\src7
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at findEmptyDataInCompiledData (D:\githubprojects\)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/proces)
    at async D:\githubprojects\projectMovieSite\dizite8
PS D:\githubprojects\projectMovieSite\dizitest>
```

my catch in func

```
catch (err) {
    logger.error(`${err}`)
    throw Error
  }
```

How can I take detail log when I use try catch?

I tried to explain my try catch problem

Comment: try `throw err` so you're actually (re)throwing the original error, not a generic one

Comment: Don't do `throw Error;`!

Comment: @RobinZigmond  So how can I be my total err

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try this.

```js
catch (err) {
  logger.error(`${err}`);
  if(err.stack){
    logger.info(err.stack);
  }
  throw err;
}

Also you all the error instance has it's own field named stack.
```

Comment: I solve like that but if its not neccesarry